Main loop waits on thread pool despite using map_async
I have a multiprocessing thread pool with a loop running on the main thread. The main loop must run without being blocked: It issues a task to the thread pool on startup and whenever all results have been processed and a new set must be calculated, while retrieving those results that become available even when the pool is still busy.
import multiprocessing as mp

def double(x):
   return x * 2

pool = mp.Pool()
items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = None

while True:
    if result:
        for value in result.get():
            print(value)
    if not result or result.ready():
        result = pool.map_async(double, items)
    print("This should still execute even when results aren't ready!")

Despite every documentation agreeing that map_async should be non-blocking, the entire while True loop waits until they are ready. This seems to be triggered by result.get() but even this shouldn't block the main loop if using map_async hence why there's a result.ready() method to check if the entire task has finished. Is there a non-blocking version of result.get() or another approach I must use?

map_async() does not block as opposed to map(), which blocks execution until all tasks have completed. map_async() waits for the individual results of all the workers (subprocesses, not threads) to complete to present the results. That is also true for the callback function. Note that for results.get() you may specify a timeout or make t truly non-blocking setting a zero timeout but this is not going to change things in your case

As someone else confirmed, it seems result.get() is always meant to block: My expectation was that if using map_async instead of map the result.get method would return partial results without blocking. What's required is imap or imap_unordered which successfully delivers a list of results that are finished when called rather than waiting until everything is ready.

Your description of imap and imap_unordered is a bit imprecise. These method both return an iterator (it does not "deliver a list") and calling its next
method (either explicitly or implicitly using for result_value in ...) returns the next result returned from your worker function when it becomes available or raises a StopIteration exception when all the results have already been iterated.
